# Update Child table Whose Parent Table has duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have duplicate data in Contact Table.
Using Rank() function i am identifying duplicates.
I also have to update the id of contact in child table activity.

I want to update contact id in activity table by contact id of rank 1 where rank 2 or above are there.

---

**Using this query to find duplicate contact**

```
(SELECT  
    ExternalContactID,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ExternalAccountId, Name, Email, MailingCity, 
    MailingCountry, MailingState, MailingStreet, Phone ORDER BY 
    ExternalContactID) AS rank

FROM 
    contact)
```

Table: Contact

```
ExternalContactID | Rank
    101           |  1
    102           |  2
```

Child table: Activity

```
ActivityID    |    ContactID
    1         |        101
    2         |        102
```

Before deleting contact(s) which have rank > 1, I need to update the child table "Activity" with rank 1 contact id.

Result:

Contact with id = 102 is deleted and Activity Record with id = 2 now has contact id = 101

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You have defined a business need but did not say what you need help with. It would be a huge help if you could post table definitions and some sample data. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: ExternalContactID | Rank 
     101          |  1 
     102          |  2

Comment: That is not helpful, you posted that in the question. It still doesn't make any sense. Look at the link I sent you.

Comment: F.e. two more fields in Contract like `(103, 1),(104,2)` how you will know that `102` in `Activity` table should be changed to `101` and not for `103`?

Answer (score 0):

You've used RANK to identify groups of duplicates and the one in each group you wish to keep.  This is your mechanism for doing a self-join to relate every row to the "keeper" (the member of the duplicate group you wish to keep).

```
WITH cte AS (
  {Query with Rank column}
)
  SELECT ... 
  FROM cte a
  INNER JOIN cte b
    ON {all the partitioning columns being equal}
    AND a.Rank=1
    AND b.Rank<>1
```

With the psuedocode above,  you've got all the rows in the table joined to the row that is going to be the "keeper" after you delete the duplicates.   JOIN to this structure in your UPDATE to set the FK to the PK of the "Keeper" that is related to it.